# fetching data from json and check whether available in an array

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays, json

I have the following code to get a json response using ajax. From the response I am taking the "prodId".
More responses are coming to the page when the page load and each response will contain different "prodId"s. I need to check the "prodId" is already recieved or not.
I have some divs already in the page with the above recieved prodId.

I am new to handling array. One thing to remember that all the json responses are coming in the page load itself. So after getting the first response I need to check any duplicate  response is coming and should avoid it. Please help me out

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "jsonp",

success: function(data){
  prodId = data.prodID;
  //populate this data in page
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add something to the elements that will help you identify them based on `prodID`. Element ID would be a good fit here, but in case you're using something else for that, just add another class.

```
newElement.addClass('prod-' + data.prodID);
```

Then when deciding whether to add a new element to the DOM, just check if:

```
if($('.prod-' + data.prodID).length == 0) { ... }
```

You could of course make a local dictionary and perform the lookup in memory rather than in DOM:

```
var addedProducts = {};
```

Each time you add an element to the DOM:

```
addedProducts[data.prodID] = newElement;
```

When deciding whether to add an element to the DOM:

```
if(!addedProducts.hasOwnProperty(data.prodID)) { ... }
```

---

The complete code could look something like this:

```
success: function(data){
  prodId = data.prodID;

  if($('.prod-' + prodId).length == 0) {
     var newElement = $('<div/>').html(some content as determined by data);
     newElement.addClass('prod-' + prodId);
     newElement.appendTo('body');
  }
});
```

Of course, how you create your elements and where you append them depend on what you want to achieve. I trust you have this figured out under your "populate this data in page" comment. All you need to add is the `addClass` call, and the wrapping `if`.

Comment: Thanks David, But I didnt understand the solution because I am new to JQuery

Comment: David I tried your code and is really helpful for me. Thank you very much :) 
One more doubt, Is there any way to avoid the json call from being fired if duplicate product are there.